# How can I use 0 instead of NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, coalesce

Check out the query below:

```
WITH TEMP([Company], [Company Name], [GL Description], [Amount], [BeginBal])
AS
(
    SELECT 
       GLAC.GLCo AS Company, 
       HQCO.Name AS 'Company Name', 
       GLAC.Description AS 'GL Description', 
       SUM(GLDT.Amount) AS Amount, 
       GLYB.BeginBal 
    FROM 
       GLAC 
    LEFT JOIN 
       HQCO ON GLAC.GLCo = HQCO.HQCo
    LEFT JOIN 
       GLDT ON GLAC.GLCo = GLDT.GLCo AND GLAC.GLAcct = GLDT.GLAcct
    LEFT JOIN 
       GLYB ON GLAC.GLCo = GLYB.GLCo AND GLAC.GLAcct = GLYB.GLAcct
    WHERE 
       GLAC.udCategory = 'Cash At Bank' 
       AND GLAC.Active = 'Y'  
       AND (GLAC.GLCo = 1 or GLAC.GLCo = 5 or GLAC.GLCo = 6 or GLAC.GLCo = 7) 
       AND GLYB.FYEMO = '2012-06-01 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY
       GLAC.GLCo, HQCO.Name , GLAC.Description, GLYB.BeginBal
)
SELECT
    Company, [Company Name], [GL Description], Amount + BeginBal as 'Balance' 
FROM 
    TEMP
```

This produces the below table:

```
 +---------+----------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
| Company |     Company Name     |        GL Description        |   Balance   |
+---------+----------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
|       1 | Contracting Pty Ltd  | Cash At Bank ANZ Cheque a/c  | -8423347.81 |
|       1 |  Contracting Pty Ltd | Investment Online Saver Acct | 15040000    |
|       1 |  Contracting Pty Ltd | Westpac Bonus Cash Reserve   | 123133      |
|       5 | ABC UTC PTY LTD      | Cash At Bank ANZ Cheque a/c  | 13121902.53 |
|       6 | ABC UTC PTY LTD      | Cash At Bank ANZ Cheque a/c  | 3932872.45  |
|       6 | ABC UTC PTY LTD      | Investment Online Saver Acct | 142448      |
|       7 |  Plant Hire Pty Ltd  | Cash At Bank ANZ Cheque a/c  | 253253.32   |
+---------+----------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Some of my data is missing and this is because of this line:

```
GLYB.FYEMO = '2012-06-01 00:00:00'
```

The problem is that some records in 'GLAC' do not have a value in GLYB therefore, the null value does not appear in my table.

How can I make all records appear if any of these conditions apply:

- `GLYB.FYEMO = '2012-06-01 00:00:00'`
- `GLYB.FYEMO is null`

Comment: You might want to choose a different title for your question. "How can I use 0 instead of NULL in MSSQL" doesn't imply that you have an issue with missing results in a query that uses outer joins, which appears to be your actual issue.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Do the missing results have values on GLAC otherwise meeting the conditions in the WHERE clause? Every condition in the WHERE clause will filter your results, regardless of what matches there might be in the joins with the other tables.

Comment: Yes they do.   The GLYB table is a list of balances for each year between 2011 and 2014, I want to use only the balance from 2012 and some records do not have a balance for this year. In this case, I want to use 0

Comment: Have you tried `GLYB.FYEMO IN('2012-06-01 00:00:00',NULL)`?

Comment: Your question has a coalesce tag.  That's a good function to use.  However your code is to unreadable for me to figure out the right spot.

Comment: can you try AND (GLYB.FYEMO = '2012-06-01 00:00:00' OR GLYB.FYEMO is null) ?

Comment: @ah_hau I asked him that question before deleting that as an answer and he said he tried (or field is null) already.

Comment: ok, how about AND ISNULL(GLYB.FYEMO, '2012-06-01 00:00:00') = '2012-06-01 00:00:00'

Comment: No @Edper, did you try that? You can't do equality comparisons to NULL.

Comment: anything that come into my mind is it might be not null, is empty, try compare with ''

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move the condition to the `on` clause, because the `where` turns the outer join to an inner join:

```
WITH TEMP([Company], [Company Name], [GL Description], [Amount], [BeginBal]) AS (
      select GLAC.GLCo as Company, HQCO.Name as [Company Name], GLAC.Description as [GL Description], 
             SUM(GLDT.Amount) as Amount, GLYB.BeginBal
      from GLAC LEFT JOIN
           HQCO
           ON GLAC.GLCo = HQCO.HQCo LEFT JOIN
           GLDT
           ON GLAC.GLCo = GLDT.GLCo and GLAC.GLAcct = GLDT.GLAcct LEFT JOIN
           GLYB
           ON GLAC.GLCo = GLYB.GLCo and
              GLAC.GLAcct = GLYB.GLAcct and
              GLYB.FYEMO = '2012-06-01 00:00:00' 
      where GLAC.udCategory = 'Cash At Bank' and GLAC.Active = 'Y'  and
            (GLAC.GLCo in (1, 5, 6, 7)
      Group By GLAC.GLCo, HQCO.Name , GLAC.Description, GLYB.BeginBal
     )
Select Company, [Company Name], [GL Description], Amount + BeginBal as Balance
from TEMP;
```